# Reset app password which was saved initially

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my project by default bitbucket app password is setup i want to remove it so that if i push the code it should ask me app password every time.

Any solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your app password is stored by a git credential helper:
(assuming your `git remote -v` shows an HTTPS URL)

```bash
git config --global credential.helper
xxx

# replace xxx by the actual value from the previous command
print "host=bitbucket.org\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get

# if you see the app password, remove it with:
print "host=bitbucket.org\nprotocol=https\nusername=you" | git credential-xxx erase
# (replace you by your BitBucket account)
```